# importation and subsequent use of a tab delimited text file in networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, network-programming, networkx, csv

I have a large tab2 file that I have imported in python. In the 15th and 16th column of the file- individual, cellular interactions are documented in a descending format like so:

```
          Protein A    Protein B
           A1            B1
           A2            B2
        etc. so A1 interacts with B1 and so on....
```

I need to extract these interactions into lists- "dataA and dataB" (although I'll be doing it in files later).

However once I have done this what I need to use these lists/ files to create a graph to represent the overall pathway (using networkx). So I figure that I need to bind the lists in such a way that A1 will be across from B1- it's interactor....

I would do it in some way similar to this:

```
                 a = numpy.Protein A(1000)
                 b = numpy.Protein B(1000)
                 numpy.column_stack((a,b))
```

However this numpy created array may not be suitable for input into networkx as I am told that networkx requires it's input in tuples for the command e.g.

```
            "G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3)])"....
```

So my question is: am I going about this the right way? Or should I be concentrating first on getting the data into networkx in away that suits networks? Or is there some way that I'm not considering to enter my data into it networkx as an array?

Comment: Can you say what exactly it is you want for a given input?  Explicitly list exactly what the edges would be.  This seems like it will be very straightforward, but it just needs to be a bit clearer what you want.

Comment: Give a specific (short) sample input that is close enough to what you've got, and it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is the following:

1) iterate through your list of interactions and build a list of proteins by appending the protein names to a list.

2) after creating a `networkx` object, for each node, use `add_node` to add it to the network.

3) Iterate again through your original interaction list, and use `add_edge` to draw connections between the nodes.

No need to use `numpy` at all

Comment: oh ok thanks Ryan. I realise that I should use a for loop to get the add-node command to iterate through the list but I can't imagine how I'm going to specify the individual interactions as there are so many of them...?

Comment: It's not clear what you think is difficult about having so many individual interactions.  Why does that cause a problem?  Just use `G.add_edge(proteinA, proteinB)` for each pair that's already in the list.